# Exact match except for leading and trailing special characters including whitespaces

Tags: shell, awk

I am trying to have awk search for exact matches except for leading and trailing special characters and whitespace.

e.g.

searching for 'Hello':

```
Matches:
$%#@!@@[Hello ^%.!
hello world
```

but WONT match:

```
helloworld
```

I have partial matches working like so:

```
(tolower($0) ~ /hello/)
```

but cant figure out how to do the special characters.

By 'Special' characters, I mean non letter/number characters:

!@#$%^&*()-[]:"><'.,/?\|~`

Comment: Please don't blindly apply tags, e.g. the "linux" tag is completely misplaced. Read the description!

Comment: What do you mean by "special characters"? Punctuation? Control characters? non-alpha-numeric? regexp metachars? Something else? There are no "special" anything in software so any time you find yourself writing the word "special" (or "new") take a minute to really think about what it is you're trying to convey and then choose the appropriate word or words to use instead of "special" (or "new").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you trust `awk`'s word boundary

```
$ awk 'tolower($0) ~ /\yhello\y/' file

$%#@!@@[Hello ^%.!
hello world
```

but will filter out "helloworld"

I think `\y` is only supported by `gawk`, otherwise you can use `\<` and `\>` for left and right boundaries...

Comment: The `\y` depends on GNU awk, btw.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat ip.txt
helloworld
hello_world
$%#@!@@[Hello ^%.!
hello world

$ grep -iE '(^|[^[:alnum:]])hello([^[:alnum:]]|$)' ip.txt
hello_world
$%#@!@@[Hello ^%.!
hello world
```

- `-iE` for case insensitive match and using ERE
- `(^|[^[:alnum:]])` start of line or non alphabet/digit character
- `hello` string to match
- `([^[:alnum:]]|$)` followed by non alphabet/digit character or end of line

If you include `_` as well as a valid character, then

```
$ grep -iw 'hello' ip.txt
$%#@!@@[Hello ^%.!
hello world
```